# Transforming data table

Tags: r

I would like to rearrange my data table. I have my data arranged as the `df` in the example but I would like to see it as in `new.df`

```
Name <- c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3")
Absorbance <- c(25, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 50, 60, 40)
Wavelength <- c("One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two", "Three", "One", "Two", "Three")
df <- data.frame(Name, Absorbance, Wavelength)

New.name <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
One <- c(25, 5, 50)
Two <- c(15, 10, 60)
Three <- c(20, 15, 40)

new.df <-data.frame(New.name,One, Two, Three)
```

Comment: Give a more specific description of what you want please

Comment: I want to have In the name column three rows with a1, a2, and a3. then three more columns with One, Two, and Three where absorbance will be written from the corresponding wavelength. Not sure if I'm clear, I will update the example to be a bit clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "aggregation", which can be achieved with a number of R base functions: `aggregate`, `tapply`, `by`, or `xtabs`. Examples:

```
> aggregate(. ~ Name + Wavelength, df, FUN=sum)
  Name Wavelength Absorbance
1   a1        One         25
2   a2        One          5
3   a3        One         50
4   a1      Three         20
5   a2      Three         15
6   a3      Three         40
7   a1        Two         15
8   a2        Two         10
9   a3        Two         60
```

This is a data frame where the combination of column values provide the index. If you want to have a table with two indices, you can use `xtabs`:

```
> res <- xtabs(Absorbance ~ Name + Wavelength, df)
> res
    Wavelength
Name One Three Two
  a1  25    20  15
  a2   5    15  10
  a3  50    40  60
```

The result of `xtabs` is not a `data.frame`, but a `table` which you can directly address with the row and column names:

```
> res["a1", "One"]
[1] 25
```

Comment: This works! But, when I apply it to my data set I have a small issue, due to the fact that I have 2 replications of each observation. Imagine if there are 2 absorbance values for a1-One. The script will combine both values, but i would like to keep them separate.

Comment: @art%c5%abrs-katamadze You can group by more than two fields, e.g. `xtabs(Absorbance ~ Name + Name2 + Wavelength, df)`.